# Website Speed 'Connect Time'

Tags: performance, web, pagespeed, page-load-time

After noticing a drastically slow load time on one of my website I started running some tests on Pingdom - http://tools.pingdom.com/

I've been comparing 2 sites, and the drastic difference is the 'Connect' time. On the slower site its around 2.5 seconds where as on my other sites its down around 650ms. I suppose its worth mentioning the slower site is hosted by a different company.

Thew only definition Pingdom offers is "The web browser is connecting to the server". I was hoping

1. Someone could elaborate on this a little for me, and
2. Point me in a direction of resolving it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Every new TCP connection goes through a three-way handshake before the client can issue a request e.g. GET, to the web server.

Client sends SYN to server, server responds with SYN-ACK, client responds with ACK and then sends the request.

How long this process takes is latency bound i.e. if the round-trip to the server is 100ms then the full handshake will take 150ms, but as the client sends the request just after it sends the ACK work on the basis it's a cost of one-roundtrip.

Congestion and other factors can also affect the TCP connect time.

Connect times should be in the milliseconds range not in the seconds range - my round-trip time from the UK to a server in NY is 100ms so that's roughly what I'd expect the TCP connect time to be if I was requesting something from a server there.

See @igrigorik's High Performance Browser Networking for a really in-depth discussion / explanation - http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch02.html#TCP_HANDSHAKE